# Multiple Databases, One Doctrine Connection, and the one disobedient bundle

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Weird issue I'm having with Doctrine ORM

I have various bundles that all contain their own set of entities that all manage their own databases.  They are all managed under the same default connection.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                dbname:   "%database_dbname%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

As all of the managed databases share the same connection, the `dbname` parameter is intentionally left blank, and targeting the appropriate databases and the tables falls on me to specify in the `@Table` annotation.

My problem is that only two of the three bundles works anymore.

For sake of brevity the bundles are: AppBundle, BlogBundle, SalesBundle
Each of those manages their own set of entities under {BundleName}\Entity.  The setup is super simple, I will share the header of an entity from each bundle

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Account
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="siteengine.account", options={"comment":"Governing User Account Storage"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Account
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

That one works.

```
<?php

namespace SalesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SalesBundle\Repository\ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sales.Client", options={"comment":"Main/Primary Client Storage for Sales"})
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

That one also works.

```
<?php

namespace BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Account;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BlogBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog.posts", options={"comment":"Primary Blog Post Storage"})
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

This one does not.

And what I mean by "does not" is the doctrine commands.  I can use the Blog entities anywhere, and get back the data I want and need, but I have to manually create the tables and schema myself for the blog entities in order to test this.  For whatever reason, App and Sales bundles are working fine, any changes I make to them get reflected in the `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` outpu, but at no time, ever, does anything regarding the blog bundle get reflected in that same output.

Again, all under the same connection, two of the three bundles works with the schema tool, but all three bundles work when executing DQL commands.

I feel like, im losing my mind here

Comment: What does `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` say?

Comment: I suspect that your bundle either isn't loaded into Symfony (in the AppKernel) or its DependencyInjection/BlogExtension file isn't correctly named (a typo perhaps) or the `doctrine.orm.mappings` section for that bundle isn't declared or property configured.

Comment: Hi @MihaiStancu I can assure you that the bundle is absolutely registered, im doing all my testing with it's entities in it :) Like I said near the bottom, the DQL commands are using the entities just fine, it's jsu that I have to create the tables by hand as the doctrine command line tools are not helping me create them for the blog entities specifically (everything else though)

Comment: That said, I just ran the validate command (I hadn't even noticed that one before) and do notice it's complaining about some stuff here regarding my association mappings.  Didn't these validation errors used to show up in the update command?

Comment: Usually the validation errors which do not show up are the ones you can live with.

Comment: When you define a bi-directional relationship but forget to define the inverse  of it it (or define it without the "inversedBy" mapping) it automatically becomes a unidirectional relationship.

Comment: Those kinds of errors should never trigger any schema changes themselves. The ORM doesn't know that the relationship is bidirectional... but the columns will still be there none the less.

Comment: A fully functional controller and/or Entity and/or Repository class does not imply a fully functional/registered Bundle.

Comment: Does the `bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` command generate tables for all 3 bundles?

Comment: Hi @MihaiStancu I fixed up the associations, I get `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.` now. But the Blog tables are still not generated :\

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. And I'm not a fan of the result.

After some more playing around, I noticed if I setup my default connection `dbname` parameter to any one of the databases, and run the command it will indeed sync up. Including the blog database.

I then stumbled upon a [github project that is attempting to do exactly the same thing as me](https://github.com/lobsterdore/symfony2-multiple-db-example), and the Documentation shocked me there too as it confirmed a suspicion

> - Create the two test databases 'symfonydemo_post' and
>     'symfonydemo_user';
> - You can build the databases automatically, simply
>     set the db name in parameters.yml to 'symfonydemo_post' and run 'php
>     app/console doctrine:schema:update' to create the tables, change the
>     db name to 'symfonydemo_user' and repeat the process to build the
>     tables for the User entity.

Whelp.. I guess thats cool that you can have a little bit of control over the cli..........................................

Comment: This is a particularly unexpected behavior.